# Cannot `git rm` A Previously Tracked File

Tags: git, windows-8, msysgit, git-rm

I have a developer on a Windows 8 computer who's installed git from [Git-Scm](http://git-scm.com/download/win) who can't use `git rm` to remove files from his repo.

`git --version` output:

```
version 1.8.1.msysgit.1
```

When he attempts to untrack the file, he gets this message:

```
fatal: pathspec '<path>' did not match any files
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, we've tried a variety of ways of entering the path from Windows (`./folder/file`, `"./folder/file"`, `folder/file`, `"folder/file"`) and none of the attempts have worked so far.

I could just remove the files on my machine if I wanted, but I'd like to know what the issue is with Git here.  Why can't he `git rm` files?

Comment: Could you show the full `git rm` command used? I might be able to help then.

Comment: @IamJohnGalt `git rm ./app/views/bonds/apply.ctp` is one example, but like I said above, I also tried it with/ without the leading `./` and with/ without `"`, none of which allowed me to remove it from the repo.  It always comes back with that error `fatal: pathspec "/app/views/bonds/apply.ctp" did not match any files`.

Comment: We've also tried reversing the slashes (`folder\file`, `.\folder\file`) and that wasn't cutting it either.

Comment: are you sure the file you want to remove is tracked by git? what is the output of `git log <file-path>`?

Comment: @CharlesB Yep, it's being tracked by git.  When I tried to do a `git log <filepath>` it gave the error `fatal: ambiguous argument 'app/views/bonds/apply.ctp': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`.  This simply wasn't the case, however.  I see it in git and everything else.  I finally did find a workaround that worked however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using git through the command line wasn't working, period.  And yes, we know the difference between a tracked and untracked file guys, we aren't git retarded.

I eventually fired up the gui, and *only* through that were we able to properly remove the file.  This has been an issue before, so I think it's a bug in Git-Scm's bash prompt.

## EDIT:

Actually, I'm quite literally retarded.  `git commit <removed file>`

http://ragefaces.s3.amazonaws.com/5041f6fdae7c704ffe000001/facepalm.png

Comment: I see, was it that the instance of deleting the file was never committed in the first place?

Comment: It was committed, just needed to commit the removal. Durp.

Comment: Yup, I just wanted to make sure I understood. Thanks.